# Numpy, Scipy: trying to use dot product in cdist for normalized vectors, yields slower than cosine

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I work with L2-normalized vectors, so I wanted to make it faster in `cdist` by using just dot product instead of cosine, which computes norm as well (which is unit in my case). The only thing that I need additionally is to check that one of the vectors was specifically assigned to be all-zeros (it is done intentionally on the previous stages of the algorithm, so I believe no approximate checks using eps are needed). Here is a comparison:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

import numpy as np


#generate 1001 normalized vectors

vec = np.random.rand(1,1000) # 1 vector
vecs = np.random.rand(1000,1000) # 1000 vectors

#normalize:
vec = vec/np.linalg.norm(vec)
vecs = np.array([vec/np.linalg.norm(vec) for vec in vecs])

# I want this check, it is important for me
nullvect = np.zeros(1000)



import time

# ordinary cos - looks like it is implemented in python in distance.py: 
'''
In [72]: cosine(a, b)
/Users/warren/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py:329: 
  dist = 1.0 - np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))
'''
start = time.time()

d = cdist(vec,vecs,metric='cosine')

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))


#simplified distance function - just dot product:
def dist_func(vec1,vec2):
    if np.array_equal(vec1,nullvect) or np.array_equal(vec2,nullvect):
        return np.nan

    return 1-np.dot(vec1,vec2)

#  Faster(?) func:
start = time.time()

d = cdist(vec,vecs,dist_func)

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))
```

However, the results are very discouraging:

```
Time elapsed: 1.184225082397461ms  //cosine
Time elapsed: 12.001752853393555ms   //simplified
```

What can I do to achieve speedup?

EDIT: Looks like the slowest part is `np.array_equal()`. If I remove it, the code runs just a little bit slower than cosine:

```
Time elapsed: 1.2218952178955078ms  //cosine                                                                                                                                  
Time elapsed: 1.550912857055664ms   //simplified
```

But it is important for me to have `np.nan` for `nullvect`.

---

EDIT2: Explanation why I need `nullvect`:

The reason why I need this check is that I compare word vectors in word2vec model, and I have manually assigned vectors for unknown words to zero arrays(or can take something else). It is convenient for me to have `nan`s as the result, because they are not taken into account when I threshold the results of `cdist`. For example, here I have two corresponding arrays - `word_vectors` with actual vectors, and list `word_data` with different data associated with these words - number of occurrences, positions in text, etc. So after thresholding `dists` I can easily apply resulting mask to subset`word_data`:

```
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    if word_vectors:
        dists = cdist([word1.vector], word_vectors, distance_func).ravel()


# nan's are not taken into account in queries like ">" or "<"
very_close_ones = [i < high_similarity_threshold for i in dists]
close_ones = [i < similarity_threshold for i in dists]
distant_ones = [i > unsimilarity_threshold for i in dists]

# let's select the places of the closest words
places = list(compress(word_data, very_close_ones))

places2 = list(compress(word_data, close_ones))
places3 = list(compress(word_data, distant_ones))
```

---

EDIT3:
I've just found that for my needs I can replace `nullvect` with `nan` vector:

```
nullvect = np.array([np.nan]*1000)
```

Then `np.dot` produces single `nan` as the result which is ok for me. The problem that remains it `np.dot` being slower than cosine.

```
def dist_func(vec1,vec2):
    return 1-np.dot(vec1,vec2)

Time elapsed: 1.268625259399414ms
Time elapsed: 1.4104843139648438ms
```

---

EDIT4:

It seems I found the solution, using matrix multiplication:

```
start = time.time()
#d2 = 1-vecs.dot(vec.T)
d2 = 1-vec.dot(vecs.T) # this order even the shape is the same, but seems to be a little bit slower (~0.02ms average)

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))
```

This yields speedup at last:

```
Time elapsed: 1.238107681274414ms  //cdist, cos
Time elapsed: 0.3299713134765625ms //matrix-vector dot product
```

I've checked numerical results, they seem correspond.

Working code:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

import numpy as np


#generate 1001 normalized vectors

vec = np.random.rand(1,1000) # 1 vector
vecs = np.random.rand(1000,1000) # 1000 vectors

#normalize:
vec = vec/np.linalg.norm(vec)
vecs = np.array([vec/np.linalg.norm(vec) for vec in vecs])

# I want this check, it is important for me
nullvect = np.array([np.nan]*1000) #np.zeros(1000)

vecs[0] = nullvect

import time

# ordinary cos - looks like it is implemented in python in distance.py: 
'''
In [72]: cosine(a, b)
/Users/warren/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py:329: 
  dist = 1.0 - np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))
'''
start = time.time()

d = cdist(vec,vecs,metric='cosine')

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))


#simplified distance function - just dot product:
def dist_func(vec1,vec2):
    return 1-np.dot(vec1,vec2)


#  Faster(?) func:
start = time.time()

#d2 = 1-vec.dot(vecs.T)
d2 = 1 - vecs.dot(vec.T)

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start))) 

#print(d.shape)
#print(d2.shape)
print(d.ravel()[:5])
print(d2.ravel()[:5])
```

Result:

```
Time elapsed: 1.190185546875ms
Time elapsed: 0.3883838653564453ms
[        nan  0.24669413  0.25673153  0.24910682  0.26340765]
[        nan  0.24669413  0.25673153  0.24910682  0.26340765]
```

Thanks everyone!

---

EDIT5:

For the one, who wants to use it, please beware:

```
>>> nullvect = np.array([np.nan]*300)
>>> nullvect2 = np.array([np.nan]*300)
>>> np.array_equal(nullvect,nullvect2)
False
```

So use

```
>>> np.isnan(nullvect).any()                                                                                                                                          
True
```

Comment: Your code crashes at `d = cdist(vec,vecs,metric='cosine')` with the following error: `XA must be a 2-dimensional array.`

Comment: @AGNGazer Strange, I use python 3.5 and everything works..

Comment: Indeed, strange, but it works in 3.6

Comment: Buried in the documentation for `cdist` is the following nugget: <blockquote>Note that you should avoid passing a reference to one of the distance functions defined in this library. For example,:

dm = cdist(XA, XB, sokalsneath)
would calculate the pair-wise distances between the vectors in X using the Python function sokalsneath. This would result in sokalsneath being called (n2) times, which is inefficient. Instead, the optimized C version is more efficient...</blockquote>